# Link Ubuntu server to GoDaddy domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, nameserver, godaddy

I have a web server hosted via prgmr.com and I would like to link it with my recently purchased domain name from godaddy.com.

From what I can tell from various tutorials online, I must set the nameserver for my domain in GoDaddy's control panel to the ones from my server host.

The only problem is that I was never given any nameservers for my server (it's not sold to be a web server specifically). The closest I can find to a name server would be what is returned from the command "cat /etc/resolv.conf" :

```
nameserver XX.XX.XX.XX
nameserver XX.XX.XX.XX
domain xen.prgmr.com
search xen.prgmr.com
```

GoDaddy also seems to give me the option to create a nameserver with them, but I can't seem to get that to work either :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/djL7G.png

Any help? If there's something I'm not clear on, make sure to tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont really need to change the nameserver IP. You only need to change the nameserver IP if you want to manage your domain records from another provider. eg [www.pointhq.com](http://www.pointhq.com) for example.

All you need to do is insert an "A" type DNS record to point at your public IP address, in a Nameserver. This could be godaddy's, this could be any nameserver. It then gets propagated out from there. This can all be done from GoDaddy's console if you want to. As I dont manage my domains from godaddy im not sure the exact steps to do this, but its there somewhere.

One way to point a domain at a webserver is to have an A record pointing at the public IP address, and then either a CNAME or another A address pointing at the www version of it. so something like

A      9.45.12.36       example.com
CNAME  www.example.com  example.com

or

A       9.45.12.36       example.com 
A       9.45.12.36       www.example.com

Somebody might need to correct me on the first example, as I currently use the second. (also the pro-cons of doing it eitherway. I believe the CNAME is better as its just a redirect, so if your IP changes it only needs to be changed in one place)

In regards to what the hell is a CNAME and an A record have a look at the ever fruitful [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_record#DNS_resource_records) on the subject as I found it helped alot.

Also remember that it might take a little while for any changed to trickle down.